# PeriodicTable search To Perodify a Name. (Java script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm trying to search in a array which contains PeriodicElements to Perodify a given name. This link

http://www.lmntology.com/ is what exactly what I want to do. But I can't find tune the search to 
return Elements with two letters, Basically it returns the first match.

For example 
"CARL" the generic search would return - Carbon, Adamantium, Rearden, Latinum

where as "CARL" should also return - Carbon, Argon ,Latinum

Any suggestions? Or a fiddle would be greatly appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vxGL/12/

```
var table = [
            "H", "Hydrogen", "1.00794", 1, 1,
            "He", "Helium", "4.002602", 18, 1,
            "Li", "Lithium", "6.941", 1, 2,
            "Be", "Beryllium", "9.012182", 2, 2,
            "B", "Boron", "10.811", 13, 2,
            "C", "Carbon", "12.0107", 14, 2,
            "N", "Nitrogen", "14.0067", 15, 2,
            "O", "Oxygen", "15.9994", 16, 2,
            "F", "Fluorine", "18.9984032", 17, 2,
            "Ne", "Neon", "20.1797", 18, 2,
            "Na", "Sodium", "22.98976...", 1, 3,
            "Mg", "Magnesium", "24.305", 2, 3,
            "Al", "Aluminium", "26.9815386", 13, 3,
            "Si", "Silicon", "28.0855", 14, 3,
            "P", "Phosphorus", "30.973762", 15, 3,
            "S", "Sulfur", "32.065", 16, 3,
            "Cl", "Chlorine", "35.453", 17, 3,
            "Ar", "Argon", "39.948", 18, 3,
            "K", "Potassium", "39.948", 1, 4,
            "Ca", "Calcium", "40.078", 2, 4,
            "Sc", "Scandium", "44.955912", 3, 4,
            "Ti", "Titanium", "47.867", 4, 4,
            "V", "Vanadium", "50.9415", 5, 4,
            "Cr", "Chromium", "51.9961", 6, 4,
            "Mn", "Manganese", "54.938045", 7, 4,
            "Fe", "Iron", "55.845", 8, 4,
            "Co", "Cobalt", "58.933195", 9, 4,
            "Ni", "Nickel", "58.6934", 10, 4,
            "Cu", "Copper", "63.546", 11, 4,
            "Zn", "Zinc", "65.38", 12, 4,
            "Ga", "Gallium", "69.723", 13, 4,
            "Ge", "Germanium", "72.63", 14, 4,
            "As", "Arsenic", "74.9216", 15, 4,
            "Se", "Selenium", "78.96", 16, 4,
            "Br", "Bromine", "79.904", 17, 4,
            "Kr", "Krypton", "83.798", 18, 4,
            "Rb", "Rubidium", "85.4678", 1, 5,
            "Sr", "Strontium", "87.62", 2, 5,
            "Y", "Yttrium", "88.90585", 3, 5,
            "Zr", "Zirconium", "91.224", 4, 5,
            "Nb", "Niobium", "92.90628", 5, 5,
            "Mo", "Molybdenum", "95.96", 6, 5,
            "Tc", "Technetium", "(98)", 7, 5,
            "Ru", "Ruthenium", "101.07", 8, 5,
            "Rh", "Rhodium", "102.9055", 9, 5,
            "Pd", "Palladium", "106.42", 10, 5,
            "Ag", "Silver", "107.8682", 11, 5,
            "Cd", "Cadmium", "112.411", 12, 5,
            "In", "Indium", "114.818", 13, 5,
            "Sn", "Tin", "118.71", 14, 5,
            "Sb", "Antimony", "121.76", 15, 5,
            "Te", "Tellurium", "127.6", 16, 5,
            "I", "Iodine", "126.90447", 17, 5,
            "Xe", "Xenon", "131.293", 18, 5,
            "Cs", "Caesium", "132.9054", 1, 6,
                        "Ba", "Barium", "132.9054", 2, 6,
            "La", "Lanthanum", "138.90547", 4, 9,
            "Ce", "Cerium", "140.116", 5, 9,
            "Pr", "Praseodymium", "140.90765", 6, 9,
            "Nd", "Neodymium", "144.242", 7, 9,
            "Pm", "Promethium", "(145)", 8, 9,
            "Sm", "Samarium", "150.36", 9, 9,
            "Eu", "Europium", "151.964", 10, 9,
            "Gd", "Gadolinium", "157.25", 11, 9,
            "Tb", "Terbium", "158.92535", 12, 9,
            "Dy", "Dysprosium", "162.5", 13, 9,
            "Ho", "Holmium", "164.93032", 14, 9,
            "Er", "Erbium", "167.259", 15, 9,
            "Tm", "Thulium", "168.93421", 16, 9,
            "Yb", "Ytterbium", "173.054", 17, 9,
            "Lu", "Lutetium", "174.9668", 18, 9,
            "Hf", "Hafnium", "178.49", 4, 6,
            "Ta", "Tantalum", "180.94788", 5, 6,
            "W", "Tungsten", "183.84", 6, 6,
            "Re", "Rhenium", "186.207", 7, 6,
            "Os", "Osmium", "190.23", 8, 6,
            "Ir", "Iridium", "192.217", 9, 6,
            "Pt", "Platinum", "195.084", 10, 6,
            "Au", "Gold", "196.966569", 11, 6,
            "Hg", "Mercury", "200.59", 12, 6,
            "Tl", "Thallium", "204.3833", 13, 6,
            "Pb", "Lead", "207.2", 14, 6,
            "Bi", "Bismuth", "208.9804", 15, 6,
            "Po", "Polonium", "(209)", 16, 6,
            "At", "Astatine", "(210)", 17, 6,
            "Rn", "Radon", "(222)", 18, 6,
            "Fr", "Francium", "(223)", 1, 7,
            "Ra", "Radium", "(226)", 2, 7,
            "Ac", "Actinium", "(227)", 4, 10,
            "Th", "Thorium", "232.03806", 5, 10,
            "Pa", "Protactinium", "231.0588", 6, 10,
            "U", "Uranium", "238.02891", 7, 10,
            "Np", "Neptunium", "(237)", 8, 10,
            "Pu", "Plutonium", "(244)", 9, 10,
            "Am", "Americium", "(243)", 10, 10,
            "Cm", "Curium", "(247)", 11, 10,
            "Bk", "Berkelium", "(247)", 12, 10,
            "Cf", "Californium", "(251)", 13, 10,
            "Es", "Einstenium", "(252)", 14, 10,
            "Fm", "Fermium", "(257)", 15, 10,
            "Md", "Mendelevium", "(258)", 16, 10,
            "No", "Nobelium", "(259)", 17, 10,
            "Lr", "Lawrencium", "(262)", 18, 10,
            "Rf", "Rutherfordium", "(267)", 4, 7,
            "Db", "Dubnium", "(268)", 5, 7,
            "Sg", "Seaborgium", "(271)", 6, 7,
            "Bh", "Bohrium", "(272)", 7, 7,
            "Hs", "Hassium", "(270)", 8, 7,
            "Mt", "Meitnerium", "(276)", 9, 7,
            "Ds", "Darmstadium", "(281)", 10, 7,
            "Rg", "Roentgenium", "(280)", 11, 7,
            "Cn", "Copernicium", "(285)", 12, 7,
            "Uut", "Unutrium", "(284)", 13, 7,
            "Fl", "Flerovium", "(289)", 14, 7,
            "Uup", "Ununpentium", "(288)", 15, 7,
            "Lv", "Livermorium", "(293)", 16, 7,
            "Uus", "Ununseptium", "(294)", 17, 7,
            "Uuo", "Ununoctium", "(294)", 18, 7
        ];



                        $("#b").click(function () {
                         var chars = $('#st').val().split("");
                              for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                                  search(chars[i]);
                              }

                       });

                       function search (char)
                       {
                         for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                          if (table[i] === char) {
                                console.log(table[i]+" "+table[i+1]+"\n");
                         }
                       }

    }
```

This is my initial attempt, It only Matches one Character Case sensitive. I will keep updating this. Please have a look.

Comment: Loop though the search characters and compile an array of all the 2Char character neighbours.  Then loop through these and the individual characters in the query, and for each loop through the table of elements, checking for matches in the element codes.

Comment: Instead of having an array of all the elements containing 118 * 5 items, it would be better to have an array of 118 objects. It makes more sense in terms of data structure, and will make it easier to do anything meaningful with.  e.g. `var table = [
            {symbol: "H", name: "Hydrogen", weight: "1.00794", group: 1, period: 1},
            {symbol: "He", name: "Helium", weight: "4.002602", group: 18, period: 1},`

Comment: Thanks Duncan I think that's a step in the right way